# Qlik authenticate.aspx back url-param not working

Tags: qlikview

I'm using the WebTicket/iFrame method of authentication/launch, and it's all working, but I'm having problems with error handling when launching a non-existing qvw.

I attempt to call the following URL:

```
https://.../authenticate.aspx?type=html&try=/qvajaxzfc/opendoc.htm?document=Nope.qvw&back=custom.htm&webticket=foo
```

Where Nope.qvw does not exist, I am taken to a blank QVW rather than redirected to custom.htm as defined in the back param.

Additionally, a cookie is set: AccessPointSession.  After that cookie is set, another attempt using that same URL ***will*** direct the browser to the url specified in the back param.  However, obviously, I'd like to be able to redirect on the first attempt at a "try" rather than the second attempt.

Or, perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way. Fundamentally, I want to be able to have some control over the behavior when a user attempts to access a qvw that is no longer on the server.